# Bind wpf combobox to a dictionary of <string, CustomClass>, and use data of custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox, binding

I'd like to apologize in advance, I'm not a WPF developer, and I don't know all the terminology.

I have a WPF application, and in it, I have a combobox.

In the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file (which I assume is the `View` part of the `MVVM`?), I have a property of type

`public Dictionary<string, TeamData> Teams { get; }`

And I want to bind the combobox to this dictionary.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TeamsDropdown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="158,142,0,24" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" FontSize="18.667" Width="195"/>`
```

Problem is, even this binding fails `(there are no items in the dropdown)`. I know that to get the text in the combobox items to be the `key` of the selected dictionary item, I have to use `SelctedValue` or `SelectedValuePath`...
But I'm not sure which, and I can't really test it until I get it to work.

The constructor of `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Teams = TeamsData.Teams;

    var appData = Application.UserAppDataRegistry;
    object nameRegistry = null;
    object ipRegistry = null;
    object teamRegistry = null;

    if (appData != null)
    {
        nameRegistry = appData.GetValue(NameRegistry);
        ipRegistry = appData.GetValue(IpRegistry);
        teamRegistry = appData.GetValue(TeamRegistry);
    }

    PlayerName = nameRegistry?.ToString() ?? "Player Name";
    IpAddress = ipRegistry?.ToString() ?? "localhost";
    PlayerTeam = teamRegistry?.ToString() ?? Teams.Keys.First();

    NameBox.Text = PlayerName;
    AddressBox.Text = IpAddress;
    TeamsDropdown.SelectedItem = Teams[PlayerTeam];
}
```

Comment: Try this : Teams.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

Comment: I believe a simpler way would be to use `Teams.Keys`, which I've also tried, but it still shows nothing

Comment: I would use a converter in your case when binding it which converts the dictionary to a list.

Comment: In my work place, there's a team that develops WPF, and I always see what they do. You can definitely bind a dictionary to a combobox.

Comment: I've tried adding `DataContext = this;` in the constructor, but it was still not it.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait in your case each item in `ComboBox` will be of `KeyValuePair<string, TeamData>` type. `SelectedValuePath` affects what is `SelectedValue` but not display. To change which property is used for display you use [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: But for now, all I want is to bind the keys to the item source, not the values. But regardless, just for the testing, I can't even bind the `KeyValuePair` to the combobox. The problem is the binding itself.

Comment: Do you get any output errors?

Comment: Nope. The combobox is just empty. I might download snoop but it won't help me if i can't get the binding to work

Comment: DataContext = this; after Teams = TeamsData.Teams; (and check if you have data).

Comment: Awesome dude. That worked for the binding. I'll try something up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set your data context to the window.

```
DataContext = this;
```

This action will refresh all bindings. Make sure you data is correctly loaded before (after `Teams = TeamsData.Teams;` in your example).

Other solution is use observable partern with ObservableCollection and INotifyProperty to update the combobox when the data is modified.

This is the final how the final ComboBox looks like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TeamsDropdown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,142,0,24" FontSize="18.667" Width="195" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"
            SelectedValuePath="Key"
            IsEditable="False">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Value.Color, Converter={local:XnaColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy.
For your Dictionary 
I suppose that your class Teams is:

```
Public Class Teams
{
      public String PlayerName { get; set; }
}
```

declaration:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty 
TeamsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Teams", typeof(Dictionary<string, TeamData>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public Dictionary<string, TeamData> Teams { get { return (Dictionary<string, TeamData>)GetValue(TeamsProperty); }}
```

in xaml:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="PlayerName" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"                                          
    DisplayMemberPath="Value.PlayerName"/>
```